# Nginx load balancer doesn't close and move websocket connection

Tags: nginx, websocket, load-balancing

I'm using nginx to load balance a websocket cluster.

```
upstream my_cluster {
  ip_hash;
  server test01.my.com:80;
  server test02.my.com:80;
  server test03.my.com:80;
}

server {
        server_name myws.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://my_cluster /;
                proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
        location /ws{
            proxy_pass http://my_cluster ;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        }

    listen 80;
}
```

The balance works, but if I shutdown aserver, the websocket connection is not properly closed and moved. It looks like it forwarded to the down server.
Does anyone experience the same issue?
I'm using raw websocket connection, not higher protocol like stomp or socketjs.